# How to allow multiple origin domains by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Global.asax.cs file?

Tags: .net, global-asax

I'm trying to stop processing the option request from Global.asax.cs Is there anyway to allow multiple cross-domains using Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the Global.asax file?

I want to allow certain multiple domains(http://testsite.com, https://testsite.com) at once.

Is there any proper way to do this. I wannt to do this on Global.asax and here is my current code

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var response = context.Response;

        // enable CORS
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://testsite.com, https://testsite.com");
        response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM *");

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type");
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            response.End();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found an answer.
You cannot duplicate "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers or cannot give comma separated domains as value of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

Therefore you have to allow one requested domain for one time.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to get requested domain from request header
        var requestedDomain = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ORIGIN"];
        var isEnabledDomain = false;
        if (requestedDomain != null)
        {
            var enabledDomains = "http://testsite.com, https://testsite.com";
            foreach (var enabledDomain in enabledDomains.Split(','))
            {
                if (enabledDomain.Equals(requestedDomain))
                {
                    isEnabledDomain = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isEnabledDomain)
            {
                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                HttpResponse response = context.Response;

                response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", requestedDomain);
                response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM *");
                if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                {
                    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type");
                    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                    response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```